# Search form not finding content in template page

Tags: themes, templates, search, forms

I created some template pages on my wordpress theme and when I'm trying to do search for some words it returns Nothing Found. When I tried to search for words from the posts or normal pages(Not template pages) it founds it normally.

I added php file to the theme folder and I coded in:

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: example.php
*/
?>
```

Now whatever I write in this file example.php (links or paragraph) can't be found by the search form. What do I need to do?

Comment: You are trying to search the _template_ content? The text hard-coded into the _template_?

Comment: To explain the question of @s_ha_dum The WordPress search function doesn't search inside the generated HTML, but just the post content stored in the database. If you want to achieve this, you need to use a waay more powerfule search engine like e.g. ElasticSearch